# Maven environment variable used for AEM credentials in pom.xml ignored by Jenkins jobs

Tags: maven, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, aem

I am currently trying to get my Jenkins (*version 2.35*) Jobs for AEM (*6.2*) author/publishers up and running. In this setup I have Dev, Staging and Production environments. To avoid version controlling my credentials in my ***pom.xml*** I have made the use of ***environment variables*** in **maven** (*version 3.3.9*).

```
<properties>
    <aem.host>localhost:4502</aem.host>
    <aem.protocol>http</aem.protocol>
    <aem.user>${env.AEM_AUTHOR_USER}</aem.user>
    <aem.password>${env.AEM_AUTHOR_PASSWORD}</aem.password>
</properties>
```

On my local environment I have tested setting those environment variables to the correct and then incorrect values and it behaves as one would think it would.

The thing here is that when I **build** the Dev Author **job** on my **Jenkins** server, it seems to **succeed** whether the environment variables are set to the **correct values or not**. It is so weird and at this point I have no clue to what is going on. I am setting the environment variables on the Jenkins server via a simple.

```
source ~/path/to/file
```

Where *~/path/to/file* would look something like the following:

```
AEM_AUTHOR_USER="admin"
AEM_AUTHOR_PASSWORD="admin"
```

Also I should mention that previously to using environment variables in maven I had the AEM credentials directly in the pom.xml just for Dev jobs.

I'm wondering if Jenkins has cached the maven properties thus the credentials and re-setting the environment variables has no effect. I should also mention I have tried re-creating the workspace on each new build to see if it would clear some caching system but no dice.

Is Jenkins or Maven caching my maven properties somewhere that my environment variables are being ignored ?

Has anyone ran into the issue I am describing ?

Should I be using the **EnvInject Plugin** Jenkins plugin ?

Any help is welcomed.

**Thanks**,
Nicola

Answer (score 0):

In the case of my Develop Jobs it seems that Jenkins uses some sort of caching system that I wasn't able to clear. Even after deleting the workspace or deleting the cache folder in

```
/home/jenkins/.jenkins/cache
```

Anyways after trying a lot of things to attempt regaining control over the value of the AEM credentials set in my pom.xml I figured out how to control the values of the pom.xml environment variables which solved my problems. The way I did that was to install the **EnvInject Plugin** after which I was able to configure my maven environment variables individually on all my jobs. Everything works great now.